# PHP Function named after the Value of a Variable

Tags: php, html, function, variables

I have a PHP function that I need to create that executes PHP or HTML Code that is stored in a variable. That's one problem. Another problem is the fact that the function will be created multiple times and will need a unique name so I've named it after `$title` but I'm not sure if this will create the function from the value of `$title` or if it will create a function called `$title` or if it just won't work. This is my code:

```
$title = $_POST['sogo_aso_name'];
$output = $_POST['sogo_aso_output'];
```

Some Code Here...

```
function $title ($output)
{
    //Some Code Here to execute $output...
}
```

So... That's my problem. I'm not sure what will execute the $output cleanly so it can be shown on a page. And I don't know if the function will be named after the value of `$title`

Thanks for any help!

Ethan Brouwer

Comment: Why do you need a unique function with a new name each time? Pass these parameters to a single function and process the data accordingly.

Comment: are you talking about something like the `eval()` function?

Comment: Don't use `eval()`. It is a dangerous function and its use is discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `call_user_func` like this:

```
call_user_func($title, $output);
```

But it's really strange to change name of one function.

Comment: I know it's strange. I'm making a wordpress plugin that lets you add your own screen options to any page, but the code that I use needs a function for every option that will be executed when the option is clicked and also to save the values. Thanks though! This is what I need.

Comment: @EthanBrouwer IMO, this way is dangerous. You get $title from post, what will happen if input, submitted by user, contains `;`? I'd suggest to think on different solution for your situation, but this will still work until you get better way. Good luck.

Comment: For the record $title($output); should also work in the most recent versions of PHP. But make sure you filter $title properly if you are collecting it from POST, this is hella dangerous otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is unfortunately not possible. You could create namespaces if you need a common name to prefix your functions with.

```
namespace fArr {
    function func1 (args) {}
    function func2 (args) {}
}
```

To call them you can use:

```
namespace {
    fArr\func1($title, $output);
}
```

Generally you want to avoid creating totally anonymous functions. Maybe create a function that handles the title and output for all requests. Alternatively create a new object with the func name as a property and output assigned to it.

```
$title  = $_POST['sogo_aso_name'];
$output = $_POST['sogo_aso_output'];

// Store data in an object named after the value of $title
// Note that constant use of this can get very messy, and very confusing
$$title = (object) array('output' => $output);
```